# Compression of the .mat file

Tags: matlab, compression

I need to compress my .mat file to .zip and reduce it's size. It's current size is 8MB. Compressing to .zip doesn't change it's size. Also tried compressing to text file using dlmwrite and then zipping. Doing that achieved 3MB from 8, but the maximum I can use is 2MB. Is there any way to compress the file to less than 2MB? Any other saving functions?

Comment: MAT is gzip compressed HDF5, it's like putting a zip into a zip, it does not reduce the size again. What data do you have?

Comment: Weights for Neural Networks.

Comment: Try these tips: http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_oop/reduce-mat-file-size-for-saved-objects.html

Comment: These won't help. All weights are trained so there can't be any defaults, properties and I need all of them.

Comment: Your data is simply that large, there isn't much you can do. Be careful with `dlmwrite`, you probably lost some precision.

Comment: Ok. Thanks. I'll try to remove some nodes in hidden layer then.

Comment: An option that works in some cases is to use lower precision. E.g. if you're using 64bit floats, drop down to 32bit floats.

Comment: Is it crucial to have ZIP format?

Comment: Yes. I need to send the files to grading system. Restrictions: 2MB/.zip. Currently reduced number of nodes from 336 to 220, but I'll try 32bit floats and more nodes.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, Matlab offers very little in the way of compression control.  By default, all recent versions of Matlab save with compression.  You also have the option to [save with no compression](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/save.html):

> save(filename,variables,version,'-nocompression') saves the variables
>   to the MAT-file without compression. The '-nocompression' flag only
>   supports MAT-file Version 7.3. Therefore, you must specify version as
>   '-v7.3'. The variables argument is optional.

One option you could try, is to save with no compression (as above), and then try using different compression tools to see if you can externally compress the uncompressed `.mat` file smaller.  I would suggest trying something that boasts a modern highly-compressed format, such as [bzip2](http://bzip.org/) or [PAQ](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PAQ).  Honestly thought, Matlab is probably doing some custom compression for numeric data that might beat those (still wouldn't hurt to try).