# Best way to save huge data in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I have complex-valued data of double data type with length 16000000 and when I save those values as a MAT file , it is almost 70+ MB which I like to reduce further.. I guess MATLAB is using ver7 format which uses compression.

Is there any way I can compress it further ?

Saira

Comment: That depends on the data and how much of it you can stand to lose. For example, images can be saved using JPEG compression which approximates the original data but doesn’t reproduce it exactly.

Comment: you may want to cast your vector to a `float` or even `int16` if it is just integer values

Comment: take a look here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37500051/compression-of-the-mat-file